# Save and Load Data - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, load

I've written this code, and I tried to save and load Data into Unity. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameControl control;

    public float health =10;
    public float experience=10;

    public  Dictionary<string, object> Name_Dic = new Dictionary<string, object>() 
    {
        {"laura",""},
        {"steph ",""},
        {"Ryan",""},      
    };

    void Start()
    {
        control = this;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10,10,100,30),"Health"+health);
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10,40,100,30),"Experience"+experience);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath +"/playerInfo.dat");

    PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
    data.experience = experience;
    data.health = health;
    data.Name_Dic = Name_Dic;

    bf.Serialize(file, data);

    file.Close();
}

public void Load()
{
    if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath+"/playerInfo.dat"))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath+"/playerInfo.dat",FileMode.Open);
        PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();

        health = data.health;
        experience = data.experience;
        Name_Dic = data.Name_Dic;
    }
}
}

[Serializable]

class PlayerData
{
public float health;
public float experience;

public  Dictionary<string, object> Name_Dic = new Dictionary<string, object>() 
{
    {"laura",""},
    {"steph ",""},
    {"Ryan",""},      
};

public  Dictionary<string, string> Dialogs_Dic = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{
    {"A1", "Hello"},
    {"A2", "Nice"},
    {"A3", "Test"},
};
```

}

The problem now that when i click on save button , i save the health and experience int because when i click on load button i finc that these two variables are saved and loaded. My problem is with the dictionary, i can't know if when i click on button save the dictionary values are saved or not. How can i now if the dictionary values are saved when i click on function saved and loaded if i click on button load.Is there a solution for that, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> How can i now if the dictionary values are saved ... Is there a solution for that

Yes, by reading it back with [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and comparing it to your original value.